# _frozen_importlib._DeadlockError: deadlock detected by _ModuleLock('django.test.signals') at 140668266856120

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, restframeworkmongoengine

I am getting this error when I go for `python manage.py runserver`

```
error - 
    _frozen_importlib._DeadlockError: deadlock detected by _ModuleLock('django.test.signals') at 140668266856120
```

Please help me out. 
I saw other questions but it says that same model is called multiple times or same database table has been called multiple times.

Comment: as a test, did you remove migration files in your project?
just remember that never don't remove __init__.py files in migration folders

Comment: Yes, I tried after removing migrations files while init.py file was kept intact. But this didnt resolve the problem.

Comment: I made another project and another app separately with the same code, it worked. I dont know exactly...... why it is so. I t works with the same code but in different app and project at the same location. ( Just for the reference)

Comment: if you are using virtual environment, just remove your venv and created another again.

Comment: Okk... Let me check @Erfan37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by upgrading your Django version to 2.2.24 like this:

```
pip install --upgrade django==2.2.24
```

Answer (score 0):

So this issue is likely as a result of a circular import - that is, in one module you have imported one module, and in that module you have imported the other.

Such as:

Inside `notifications/serializers.py`:

```
from books.serializers import BookSerializer
```

And inside `books/serializers.py`:

```
from notifications.serializers import NotificationSerializer
```

Hence, this causes a deadlock error...and it is very hard to pinpoint the circular import because it won't tell you where this circular import has occured.